# Canonical question for using PHP SimpleXML with namespaces

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, canonical

Over and over again, people ask questions about SimpleXML (the PHP built-in XML library which is, well, *simple*), because either:

- They don't know that `:` in a tag name denotes a namespace (e.g. [most of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsimplexml%5D+colon)).
- They know what a namespace is, but don't know how to use one with SimpleXML (e.g. [most of these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsimplexml%5D+namespace)).

The problem is that most of these questions have accepted answers with either *really bad advice* (like mangling the XML with `str_replace` before parsing it), or unnecessarily specific examples, so it's hard to find a good duplicate target.

For the record, there are two ways to use SimpleXML with namespaces: the  [`->children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php), and [`->attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) methods to access the elements directly; or [`->registerXpathNamespace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) *if* you want to use XPath.

I'd like to create a (Community Wiki) canonical Q&A for this, but don't want to go around dupe-hammering dozens of questions if people disagree, or think there is already a good target somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I have started building the question and answer here: [Reference - how do I handle namespaces (tags and attributes with colon in) in SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894426/reference-how-do-i-handle-namespaces-tags-and-attributes-with-colon-in-in-si/)

To do (help welcome...):

- Add examples using default namespace, and accessing un-prefixed attributes ([not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672635/xml-namespaces-and-unprefixed-attributes)!)
- Add an extra section / answer on using XPath and registerXpathNamespace
- Add an extra section / answer on creating / editing namespaced XML
- Maybe make it less wordy (a personal weakness).
- Start closing duplicates against it, copy in good bits from other people's answers, and notify them with a comment.
- Figure out how to mark the question as Community Wiki as well as the answer, as I've seen on other Reference questions. (Or should I just enjoy the reputation boost?)

As I say above, there are potentially dozens of duplicates for this, so I want to proceed slowly and make sure I don't tread on any toes.